# Rails 3 carrierwave-azure Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError OutOfRangeInput (400): One of the request inputs is out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm trying to use the carrierwave and carrierwave-azure gems to save uploaded files in my app to the azure storage blob. The documentation for the carrierwave-azure gem seems a bit lite on github, but I believe have followed all the setup directions correctly (https://github.com/unosk/carrierwave-azure). However it still doesn't work.

When I attempt to upload a file I get the following error:

> Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError in DownstreamsController#create
>   OutOfRangeInput (400): One of the request inputs is out of range.

My carrierwave.rb looks like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.azure_credentials = {
    storage_account_name: 'myaccountname',
    storage_access_key:   'reallylongstringwithcapandlowercaselettersand+signs=='
  }
  config.azure_container = 'http://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/shipmentdocs'

end
```

My uploader:

```
 include CarrierWave::RMagick
 storage :azure

def store_dir
   "http://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/shipmentdocs/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

 version :thumb do
     process :convert => 'jpg'  
     process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
   end

 def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf doc)
   end
```

I've included both gems in my gem file. If I switch the storage from :azure to :file the upload works however it stores in the app directory, I want to store the file as a blob in Azure.

Not sure that it matters, but I am trying to do this from my local dev environment via localhost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here are the request parameters being submitted:

> ```
> > {"utf8"=>"✓", 
> > "authenticity_token"=>"X/Q1ADOLgdaLJVsdrerdHdK9S/kJtSfjkjiutEuYsTYRY=",
> > "downstream"=>{"bols_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"file_name"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000107c58340
> > @original_filename="test-azure-storage-bol-file.png", 
> > @content_type="image/png",  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
> > name=\"downstream[bols_attributes][0][file_name]\";
> > filename=\"test-azure-storage-bol-file.png\"\r\nContent-Type:
> > image/png\r\n", 
> > @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dc/y286vygx1jq5wjw3f6b6bcww0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140514-8268-ngdw0m>>}},
> > "sales_order"=>"RTEWW423",  "to_company_id"=>"2", 
> > "ship_date"=>"2014-05-14",  "ship_total_pallets"=>"1", 
> > "downstreamDetails_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"tb_product_type_id"=>"17", 
> > "ship_total_net_weight"=>"3000",  "ship_total_gross_weight"=>"3000", 
> > "_destroy"=>"false"}}},  "commit"=>"Submit"}
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that in my carrierwave.rb file I was using the full URL for my config.azure_container setting (ie. 'http://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/shipmentdocs'). It turns out you should provide the container name as in:

```
config.azure_container = 'shipmentdocs'
```

It's also helpful to note that making this change requires a restart of the server for it to take effect because the carrierwave.rb file should be in your config/initializers folder.